# Formatted file reading with C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read all integers from a file and put them into an array. I have an input file that contains integers in the following format:

```
3 74

74 1

1 74

8 76
```

Basically, each line contains a number, a space, then another number. 
I know in Java I can use the Scanner method nextInt() to ignore the spacing, but I have found no such function in C++.

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);`

Comment: @ctn Why offer a C solution to a C++ question?

Comment: @Angew C ⊂ C++. Some people using C++ prefer C style formatting functions.

Comment: @ctn Almost a subset ;-) Anyway, C formatting functions are not type safe, extensible to custom types etc. I don't think they should be the default tool to use.

Comment: @Angew There are compile time checks for them though. And there are plenty of things that are really easy to do with them that are much harder C++ style.

Comment: @ctn I'm not saying "ban them." I'm just saying "don't default to them, only use them for the stream-hard bits." How do compile-time checks for variadic functions with string-based argument interpretation work, by the way?

Comment: @Angew The same way printf/scanf family functions work: iterate through the string specifiers, match the function arguments :)

Comment: @Angew Doesn't work for format strings computed at runtime. But then, if you do that you're hanging yourself.

Comment: @ctn Cool, I wasn't aware (some) compilers do that for compile-time format strings. Good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> arr;
  std::ifstream f("file.txt");
  int i;
  while (f >> i)
    arr.push_back(i);
}
```

Or, using standard algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> arr;
  std::ifstream f("file.txt");
  std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<int>(f)
    , std::istream_iterator<int>()
    , std::back_inserter(arr)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int value;
while (std::cin >> value)
    std::cout << value << '\n';
```

In general, stream extractors skip whitespace and then translate the text that follows.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this does? Sorry, I am new to C++ and the syntax is not too familiar

Comment: @red Useful search terms: stream extraction operators (or extractors), stream insertion operators (or inserters).

Comment: @red - `std::cin` is the standard input stream; `std::cout` is the standard output stream. You read from an input stream with `>>`, and you write to an output stream with `<<`. Try it. And do the search that @Angnew suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
// reading a text file the most simple and straight forward way
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
int a[100],i=0,x;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())  // if the file is found and can be opened
  {
    while ( !myfile.eof() ) //read if it is NOT the end of the file
    {

      myfile>>a[i++];// read the numbers from the text file...... it will automatically take care of the spaces :-)

    }
    myfile.close(); // close the stream
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";  // if the file can't be opened
  // display the contents
  int j=0;
  for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   {//enter code here
    cout<<a[j]<<" ";                 

 }
//getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Never iterate on `eof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Angew it would really help, If you tell Why not to

Comment: My comment is a link. Just follow it ;-)